# android files io where should i put source file

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to store a picture ,but i dont know where should i put "b.jpg" in android studio,it should be in "Drawable" or the others
PS:"b.jpg"is PC file

here is my code

```
    String externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    imgFile = externalDir + "/b.jpg";

    iv_file =  findViewById(R.id.image);
    iv_file.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);




    Button btn_img_save =  findViewById(R.id.btn_img_save);
    Button btn_img_open =  findViewById(R.id.btn_image_read);
    btn_img_save.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_img_open.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void saveBitmap(String path, Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(path));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not modify Resources (`Drawable` or `Assets`)  in apk at runtime. You have to save image in Device storage .'

Comment: understand,thank you!